# Who is Queen Choladevi?

Tags: identification-request, rishi

Who is Queen Choladevi and what is she doing with Sage Angiras in this painting?
[image]

Comment: She looks like devi Varahi.

Comment: How did you figure her name? Any reference?

Comment: Looks like a wolf.

Comment: How do you know that it is Sage Angiras in the painting?

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto Yes looks like her but she can't be Goddess Varahi because Goddess always sits on a throne and never directly on the ground.

Comment: @Rickross You're right she is not devi varahi. I found one reference: https://www.metmuseum.org/art/collection/search/37951 However it doesn't answer who is this queen.

Answer (score 1):

Queen Choladevi, whose husband was blessed by Lakshmi, the goddess of fortune, did not recognize the goddess when she came to her palace in disguise. For her disdain for the deity, the queen was cursed and given the head of a pig. She fled to the sage Angiras, who taught her the secret of the Mahalakshmi vrata, by the power of which she was returned to human form.

[Source: The Metropolitan Museum of Art](https://www.metmuseum.org/art/collection/search/37951?ft=india&ao=on&pg=17&rpp=60&pos=976)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).